# Move headers rows from under group to row just before group

Tags: vba, excel, position, row

I'm quite new to VBA programming and i already got a project to handle in my small company. Here's my problem:

We export Project Data from an ERP software and the client wants to be able to edit the data in an Excel file with formulas.

The problem is, that the "Project titles" are somehow placed under the "Project positions". I tryed to describe it better in the Print Screen. The Red Boxes show the "Project Titles"

I wanted to upload a picture, but my reputation is not good enough yet (My first post)

I will put a Imgur Link here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubalb.png

Any possibility to move entire rows with VBA? The problem is: the positions have no defined quantity. So it's necessary to work with some "marks" like the `[x]` and `[ ]` I've put in the "IST" columns.

I hope you can understand what my problem actually is.

Comment: I am quite confuse about your question and question title. What do you mean by "move entire rows" ? Are you mean copy the particular row or the rows under the project name?  The suggestion I could give is : you can record the macro and perform the require function manually. Refer back the code and understand the code.

Comment: Hi Keong Thank you for your answer.
I'm project title is for example :" Fräswagen" or "Bohrwagen".Those project titles are positioned UNDER the project positions... or details .Here is another picture trying to explain it.  
I'm trying to move the whole row of this title up like in the picture described. i think i've got a plan how to handle it now... i'm going to post the codes and everything as soon as it starts to make some sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand it properly, you want to bring up the lines of projects.

Here is something that may help you (it assume that each **line of projects is empty on the first column** and that the data start at row 3 (easily changeable here) in your sheet) :

```
Sub Faddi()
    Dim FirstDataRow As Integer, _
        LastRow As Integer, _
        RowToCopy As Integer, _
        RowToPaste As Integer

    FirstDataRow = 3

    With ActiveSheet
        LastRow = .Rows(.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        RowToCopy = .Cells(FirstDataRow, 1).End(xlDown).Row + 1

        'Insert the first row just under headers
        .Rows(RowToCopy).Copy
        .Rows(FirstDataRow).Insert Shift:=xlDown

        'Loop to find each other row to transfer
        Do While RowToCopy <= LastRow
            RowToPaste = RowToCopy
            RowToCopy = .Cells(RowToCopy + 1, 1).End(xlDown).Row + 1
            .Rows(RowToCopy).Copy Destination:=.Rows(RowToPaste)
        Loop
        'Delete last copied row to clean the file
        .Rows(RowToPaste).Delete
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi R3uK
Thank you for your Answer.
That's exactly what I intend to do. And yes. Each line of Projects is empty on the first column and the Data start at row 3.

I'm going to test out your script.

Comment: @Faddi : Did my proposition work well for your problem? Because your code may work but propably won't be easy for people to re-use. Anyway, I'm not sure your are familiar with the site, so to accept an answer, there is a tick (will turn green) under up/down vote. Click on it to mark your issue as solved! ;) And later, you can up/down vote everywhere you find useful/confusing! ;)

Comment: Hi R3uK
It didn't work out perfectly^^ the  first two rows worked well but then it kinda messed up the rest of the sheet. I know this code might be hard to reuse.. i worked with some indicators on the sheet. 
Thank you for tellking me about the "accept an answer" - thing :) i'm quite new to this website and coding in general.
Anyways i think your answer should be the accepted one.
Thanks again
Cheers

Comment: @Faddi : No problem mate, there is a start for everyone and here is the best place to look for answer and ask for question if you don't find a solution!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the help.
I found a solution for my problem which seems to work quite well.

```
Sub Finde_Die_Zelle()
Dim FindString As String
Dim Rng As Range
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim Runs As Long
Runs = 1
FindString = "[x]"
With Sheets("Tabelle1").Range("O:O")
    Set Rng = .Find(What:=FindString, _
                    After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                    LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                    MatchCase:=False)
    If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
        Application.Goto Rng, True
    Else
        MsgBox "Fertig 1"
    End If
End With
ActiveCell.Value = "[o]"
ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
'ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy
'Tabelle2.Range("A1").PasteSpecial
lastRow = Tabelle1.Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
'Do While Durchlaufe <> lastRow
FindString = "[  ]"
With Sheets("Tabelle1").Range("o:o")
Set Rng = .Find(What:=FindString, _
                    After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                    LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False)
    If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
        Application.Goto Rng, True
    Else
        MsgBox "Fertig 2"
    End If
    ActiveCell.Value = "[x]"
    ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy
End With
FindString = "[o]"
With Sheets("Tabelle1").Range("O:O")
    Set Rng = .Find(What:=FindString, _
                    After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                    LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False)
    If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
        Application.Goto Rng, True
    Else
        MsgBox "Fertig 3"
    End If
End With
ActiveCell.Value = ""
ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.PasteSpecial
Runs = Runs + 1
FindString = "[x]"
With Sheets("Tabelle1").Range("O:O")
    Set Rng = .Find(What:=FindString, _
                    After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                    LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                    MatchCase:=False)
    If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
        Application.Goto Rng, True
    Else
        MsgBox "Fertig 4"
    End If
End With
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Delete
ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Select
ActiveCell.Value = "[x]"
'Loop
End Sub
```

i know it might not look that professional but this works for me :)
Thank you all again for your inputs